# How to debug an embedded groovy script?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have an eclipse RCP project where I can run groovy scripts to create GUI and interact with the Eclipse platform, which basically wraps a GroovyScriptEngine.

Currently, I can only debug those scripts by either :

- remote-debugging from my Eclipse IDE and putting breakpoints on the java classes in the plugin, or
- adding log messages all over the script and parse the output to get a trace
- analyzing stacktraces after an error occured and filter out the intermediate java calls.

Is there any way to directly set breakpoints in the groovy scripts that are compiled by the GroovyScriptEngine instance ?